# How to create a view like Photo Library view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, customization

How to create a view like Photo Library view in iOS ? Like this

- 4 columns each row
- Can scroll up/down
- Can touch up to choose an image

[image]

Comment: `UICollectionView`? `UITableView`? `UIScrollView`? what have you tried?

Comment: All is OK ! Let's give me an idea ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing a CollectionView and it's what Apple recommended in the WWDC videos.

The number columns can be achieving by the cell size & spacing. Do you also want only 4 columns in landscape mode and on iPad display or should it display more columns?

Scrolling is supported in collection views which there are too many images to display on screen.

Image (cell) selection is also supported by collection views.

There are plenty of good tutorials for collection views but look for the more recent ones (in the last year or two) which give examples using storyboards.

Hope this helps.